# D365 C# - Retrieve Multiple and Updating Very Slow

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I'm building a console that connects to a D365 instance, finds records using fetch XML and updates those records with a specific value. It works, it is updating the records. However, it is only updating about one or two a second which is far from ideal, I have hundreds of thousands of records to update. I have seen / used console apps which update hundreds a second at least.

Am I going about what I want to do in the wrong way? There must be something in my code that is making it massively inefficient / stupid. I should also say that this is the first time I've used C# so it is possible I am doing something incredibly dumb.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;


namespace My.Crm.RetrieveMultipleConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var connectionString = @"AuthType = Office365; Url = xxxx/;Username=xxxx;Password=xxxx";
                CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

                IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

                string fetchquery = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='name' />
    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
    <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='name' operator='like' value='%Tom%' />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>";

                var multipleRequest = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                {
                    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                    {
                        ContinueOnError = false,
                        ReturnResponses = true
                    },
                    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                };
                EntityCollection accounts = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchquery));
                foreach (var c in accounts.Entities)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("accountid: {0}", c.Attributes["name"]);                
                    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpdateRequest updateRequest = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpdateRequest { Target = c };
                    multipleRequest.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
                    c.Attributes["name"] = "New Name";
                    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponse = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multipleRequest);

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out your `service.Execute(multipleRequest)` from `foreach` loop, keep it outside. That way the execution will be really `ExecuteMultipleRequest`.

```
var multipleRequest = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                {
                    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                    {
                        ContinueOnError = false,
                        ReturnResponses = true
                    },
                    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                };
                EntityCollection accounts = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchquery));
                foreach (var c in accounts.Entities)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("accountid: {0}", c.Attributes["name"]);                
                    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpdateRequest updateRequest = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpdateRequest { Target = c };
                    multipleRequest.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
                    c.Attributes["name"] = "New Name";

                }

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponse = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

Comment: @Arun Can you provide me an example of the SOAP body for executemultiplerequest? I don't know c#

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 pls create a new question with more context, thanks

Comment: @Arun Here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021029/soap-request-to-update-multiple-records-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm 
Please note that there is no code attached as we don't know about how the soap request looks like